# Anyone know how to use CCScrollView(vertical scrolling) and CCMenu together in cocos2d?

Tags: uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone, ccmenu

Anyone know how to use CCScrollView(vertical scrolling) and CCMenu together in cocos2d?Also can we use CCScrolllayer instead of CCScrollView or which on is better to use in cocos2d?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

vontio has posted a solution in cocos2dx [here](http://yui.co/make-ccscrollview-work-with-ccmenuitemimage/)

Comment: cocos2dx is almost the same as cocos2d. you can look at the code in the link and come with a cocos2d version of it.

Answer (score 0):

For cocos2d-iphone I would recommend CCScrollLayer ( which is part of cocos2d extensions:
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions

Right now CCScrollLayer only supports horizontal movement but it shouldn't be much difficult. Have a look at ccTouchMoved and try updating y co-ord (instead of x).